Azure DevOps Rest API - Creating Iteration don't work
First I call all iterations that I have in my project - and it works fine and then I want to create a new one via the API. , but the method doesn't work, I get the error:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Invalid request.

Is there an issue with this not really working properly or am I doing something wrong?
# *the Powershell code:*

# Variables
$organization = "x"
$project = "y"
$pat = "z"

$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0"

# authentication
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}

# HTTP GET
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers

# list iterations
$response.value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "Iteration Name: $($_.name)"
    Write-Output "Start Date: $($_.attributes.startDate)"
    Write-Output "End Date: $($_.attributes.finishDate)"
    Write-Output "Path: $($_.path)"
    Write-Output "----------------------------------"
}

# data for new iteration
$body = @{
    name = "blabla"
    attributes = @{
        startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
        finishDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(14).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json 

# HTTP POST
function Add-Iteration {
    param (
        [string]$url,
        [hashtable]$headers,
        [string]$body
    )
    try {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
        Write-Output "Iteration successfully added:"
        Write-Output $response
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "Error adding iteration:"
        Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

# add iteration
Add-Iteration -url $baseUrl -headers $headers -body $iterationData


In the official document, it provides an example to Add an iteration to the team.  In the example, we can see the content of the sample Request Body is the Id of an iteration. So, the iteration is created before you can use the API to add an iteration to the team.
We can also check it from the UI in Azure DevOps portal. When we need a new iteration, we need to Open Project settings > Project configuration and create the iteration paths.

Then we can open Project settings > Boards > Team Configuration > Iterations for a team to select the new iteration and add it to the team.

However, there is no documented Azure DevOps Rest API to create an iteration to the Project configuration.
We can get the actual REST API command by checking the network trace in Developer tools of Microsoft Edge. Then we can find the iteration Id we need.

After getting the iteration ID, we can use it in the request body as the sample below.
# Variables
$organization = ""
$project = ""
$pat = ""

$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0"

# authentication
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}


# HTTP GET
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers

# list iterations
$response.value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "Iteration Name: $($_.name)"
    Write-Output "Start Date: $($_.attributes.startDate)"
    Write-Output "End Date: $($_.attributes.finishDate)"
    Write-Output "Path: $($_.path)"
    Write-Output "----------------------------------"
}

#  new iteration id
$body = @"
{
    "id":  "fd61c80c-c03f-4b26-bdf6-51ceb80f190c"     # change to your iteration id
}
"@
# Add an iteration to the team
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
# By the way, in your script, you missed the -ContentType 'application/json' in the post request.
$response | ConvertTo-Json 

